# Server name in urls after domain migration - wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I migrated a domain to a new server and now I see some url's with server name in source code, instead of domain name. For example:

```
http://servername.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js
http://servername.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=4.5
```

also can't login to admin panel via proper url:

```
http://my-domain.com/wp-admin
```

redirects me to

```
http://servername.com/wp-admin
```

Site works fine beside that. How do I set this up correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **wp_options** table in the database, you'll need to change the **siteurl** value.

For full how-to [see here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Changing_the_URL_directly_in_the_database)

> 1. Backup your database and save the copy off-site.
> 2. Login to phpMyAdmin.
> 3. Click the link to your Databases.
> 4. A list of your databases will appear. Choose the one that is your WordPress database.
> 5. All the tables in your database will appear on the screen.
> 6. From the list, look for wp_options. Note: The table prefix of wp_ may be different if you changed it when installing.
> 7. Click on the small icon indicated as Browse.
> 8. A screen will open with a list of the fields within the wp_options table.
> 9. Under the field option_name, scroll down and look for siteurl.
> 10. Click the Edit Field icon which usually is found at the far left at the beginning of the row.
> 11. The Edit Field window will appear.
> 12. In the input box for option_value, carefully change the URL information to the new address.
> 13. Verify this is correct and click Go to save the information.
> 14. You should be returned to your wp_options table.
> 15. Look for the home field in the table and click Edit Field. Note There are several pages of tables inside wp_options. Look for the >
>       symbol to page through them.
> 16. In the input box for option_value, carefully change the URL information to the new address.
> 17. Verify this is correct and click Go to save the information.